# Scroll top - alternative to preventDefault() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

The preventDefault() function in my script below (see live example http://jsfiddle.net/E6MQd/ ) is causing collateral issues on some occasions. How could I adapt my code to get rid of it?

**Edit**: I should have been more specific. When I say collateral issues I mean preventing the opening of a fancy box popup for instance. See here http://goo.gl/cZgzqq (link to the newsletter fancy box is at the bottom of the page below the submit button - nothing happens when I click on it)

Many thanks,

```
//==============
//! Smooth scrolling
//==============

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function (ev) { // Added 'ev' parameter
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            ev.preventDefault(); // We're animating this, so don't let the browser try to navigate to this URL
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
            }, 'normal');
        }
    }
});


window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
function scrollFunction() {
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    if (top > 200) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: What issue are you having specifically? Please add explanation to question, as it stands now, it is too broad and the fiddle does not show any weird behaviour

Comment: What do you mean by `is causing collateral issues`? Try to be concise to tell your problem...

Comment: I should have been more specific. When I say collateral issues I mean preventing the opening of a fancy box popup for instance. See here http://goo.gl/cZgzqq (link to the newsletter fancy box is at the bottom of the page below the submit button - nothing happens when I click on it)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say what the problem was. My guess is that the problem is your "Back to top" was not animating. Here is the solution to that:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function (ev) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname)
    {
       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
       ev.preventDefault();

       if (target.length) { //this is for going to contact page
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
          }, 'normal');
       }
       else{ //this is for going to the top
           $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: 0
           }, 'normal');
       }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/E6MQd/1/)

Comment: You can just write `ev.preventDefault();` once inside the overall if since it will happen no matter what. Actually the only thing needs changing based on the target length is the scrollTop value, the rest can all be written once